# How to apply a texture all around a shape?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I am working on this racing track and would like to apply this border grass/dirt texture all around the border. It should be orientated right as well and repeat itself instead of stretching.
[image: weird uv btw]

Comment: Could you please provide more information about what you are trying to do? You currently sound quite unclear about the situation.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). I believe this could be achieved by using the *Array modifier* (to repeat the image) and the *Curve modifier* (to guide the shape).

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 I creates the track and would like to have a texture applied to its inset border, but it should be orientated and scaled accoring to the face orientation and shape.